# Not able to find error on below code ,as a beginner

Tags: python

```
print "Welcome to the error program"
    print "\n"

    # Variables declaring the user's age, casting the str to an int, and printing the result
    age_Str == "24 years old" 
    age = int(age_Str) 
    print("I'm" + age + "years old.")

    # Variables declaring additional years and printing the total years of age
    years_from_now = "3"
    total_years = age + years_from_now

print "The total number of years:" + "answer_years"

# Variable to calculate the total amount of months from the total amount of years and printing the result
total_months = total * 12
print "In 3 years and 6 months, I'll be " + total_months + " months old"

#HINT, 330 months is the correct answe
```

Comment: There are many errors in this program, you should try to run this progam and see which problems you get trying to run it, then fix them one by one until it works. Some things I can see right away are e.g. 1) wrong indentation, 2) prints without brackets, 3) invalid integers put into int(), 4) use of non-defined variables such as "total", ...

Comment: hi ewz93 ,yes you right ,task require I identify those errors ,paranthesis etc ..am pretty beginner on python ,some state   a bit challenging ..

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
print("Welcome to the error program")
print()

age_Str = "24"
age = int(age_Str) 
print("I'm", age, "years old.")

years_from_now = 3
total_years = age + years_from_now

print("The total number of years:", total_years)
total_months = (total_years * 12) + 6
print("In 6 months, I'll be ",total_months,"months old")
```

27 years in months is 27 x 12 = 324

To get 330 months, it's 324+6. Therefore, 6 months later is when the age will become 330 months.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi Nob0DY ,am a beginner on python ...the task requires I identify the errors ,name the error and make the code run .. .thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).